# Using Snakemake with Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: kubernetes, snakemake, azure-aks

Does anyone have a working example of using Snakemake with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)? If it is supported, which flags and setup are needed to use the Snakemake Kubernetes executor with AKS? What material there is out there is mostly on AWS with S3 buckets for storage.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but you can basically take [this](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#executing-a-snakemake-workflow-via-kubernetes) as a blueprint, and replace the google storage part with a storage backend that is working in Azure. As far as I know, Azure has its own storage API, but there are workarounds to expose an S3 interface (google for Azure S3). So, the strategy would be to setup an S3 API, and then use the S3 remote provider for Snakemake. In the future, Snakemake will also support Azure directly as a remote provider.

Answer (score -1):

you are aware of this already, but for the benefit of others:

Support of AKS has been build into Snakemake now. This works even without a shared filesystem. Most parts of the original [blog post](https://andreas-wilm.github.io/2020-06-08-snakemake-on-ask/) describing the implementation have made it into the official [Snakemake executor documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executor_tutorial/azure_aks.html).

In a nutshell: upload your data to blob and deploy an AKS cluster. The run Snakemake with these flags: `--default-remote-prefix` `--default-remote-provider AzBlob` and `--envvars AZ_BLOB_ACCOUNT_URL AZ_BLOB_CREDENTIAL`, where `AZ_BLOB_CREDENTIAL` is optional if you use a SAS in the account URL. You can use your Snakefile as is.